# gcc compile error: unknown type name 'File'

Tags: c, gcc

I am learning how to use File I/O using C.

This is the code in my file, test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    File *fp;
    char *mode = "r";
    fp = fopen("testFile", mode);
    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file testFile\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

When I compile my code using : gcc -o test test.c

I get the error :

```
atria:~/471/a4> gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘File’
     File *fp;
     ^
test.c:10:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     fp = fopen("testFile", mode);
        ^
```

I thought that maybe I was using the wrong header file but I have included stdio.h

Does anyone have any ideas as to why i'm getting this error? Thank you in advance

Comment: The type is `FILE` capitals.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you see it spelled `File` somewhere?

Comment: `man fopen` would have answered this question in a few seconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That should be `FILE`, not `File`.

Comment: Thank you, I must have overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fp = fopen("testFile", "r"); // Correct statement to open a file
    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file testFile\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```